# CodeIgniter: how to translate the URL in the selected language

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm working on a project with CodeIgniter. I am using the specific language class to show the content in different languages. Now I need to translate the URL in the selected language.

For example: `www.domain.com/book/category` to `www.domain.com/buch/kategorie`

How can I do it?

Comment: i think that you need to write the .htaccess rule for URLs.

Comment: Hi, there is no other way?

Comment: I am not sure... but i tried with the same scenario with .htacess only.

Comment: As I rarely used .htaccess I do not know how to change the url.

Answer (score 2):

1. I think, you can use route fo this, as:

   route['buch/kategorie'] = 'book/category';
2. The second aspect of the problem - the generation of links in different languages for view. You should write some code for this

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create different controllers showing the same views `(that should be translated themselves)` then links will make call to relevent controller language.

> this will work only if you decide to make your urls like `host/lang/something`
>
> > like  `www.domain.com/en/book/category` to `www.domain.com/de/buch/kategorie` if your controllers are named `en` and `de`
> >
> > > Controllers' and functions' names should be saved in languge files
>
> You can search here on stackoverflow for methods about setting language from cookies or session if are not already doing this

If you find any better suggesstion please share

Comment: Hi Omar, I created two languages as suggested and put two files called home_lang in the language folders like this: language/en/home_lang and language/de/home_lang. The translations are working fine. According to your suggestion I have to create two controllers en and de and put them in the language folder. Now I am bit confused :-(

Comment: you can strore the functions of both controllers in a `model` or create a `module` an make use of HMVC aspect of code igniter. so you can pass results to the `$data` array in the controollers (both)

Comment: Code igniter is the best for me, but i always face this kind of problems so this is one kind of solution, if you want another, i have a bunch of em